# cpio archive with folder named . (only a single dot character)

Tags: macos, cpio

I'm trying to make an install package for Mac OS from my Linux PC. For this purpose I need to pack my folders with data inside the (POSIX.1) portable format archive. This archive should have the folder named dot in the root and the rest of the folders under it, like this (I've took Adop OpenJDK Mac OS install package as an example):

```
$ cpio -itv < ./flat/base.pkg/PayloadJDK
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root            0 Oct 20 10:36 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root            0 Oct 20 10:36 ./Library
```

folder Library located inside folder named dot. But when I try it with the following commands:

```
$ mkdir -p root/Applications/Test.app
$ touch ./root/Applications/Test.app/testFiles
$ ( cd root && find . | cpio -o --format odc --owner 0:80 ) > Payload
```

I've got:

```
$ cpio -itv < ./Payload                                              
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     80              0 Feb 10 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     80              0 Feb 10 10:29 Applications
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     80              0 Feb 10 10:30 Applications/Test.app
-rw-r--r--   1 root     80              0 Feb 10 10:30 Applications/Test.app/testFiles
```

Folder Applications located in the archive root folder with the empty folder named dot.

In the first case archive root folder contains a single folder named dot in the second case archive root folder contains 2 folders: folder named dot with no content inside and a folder named Applications. I need folder Applications to be inside folder named dot like in the first case. I've tried different combinations of cpio options with no success.

Edit:
The look of the first archive in the 7zip:
[image: Look of the first archive in 7zip]

The look of the second (my) archive in the 7zip:
[image: Look of my archive in 7zip]

Edit 2: find . command output:

[image: find . output]

Comment: `.` is the current working directory. There is no difference between `./Applications` and `Applications`.

Comment: I see your confusion. It is true for Linux, but in this case there is a difference, check the cpio output in my question and you will see that in the first case Library folder is shown as a subfolder of dot folder: "./Library" but in my case Applications folder is not a subfolder of dot folder. And when I check both archives in the 7zip Gui I see the difference there is literally a folder named dot in both cases in first case when I open it I see folder Library in the second case it is empty.

Comment: I've added the 7zip screens of both archives to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: What is the `Applications` directory a subdirectory of? I don't see any option for it to be a subdirectory of anything other than its parent, e.g., `.`. FYI, a "directory" maps to a specific location on a file system. A "folder" is a logical concept that may map to one or more directories.

Comment: Applications folder located in the root of my archive alongside with a dot directory. The second screenshot shows that my archive's root contains an empty folder named dot Size 0, Folder 0 Files 0 and a folder named Applications. The first screenshot shows that Jdk archive's root folder contains folder named dot Size 324195771 Folders 103 Files 518. My goal is that my archive look like the Jdk archive i.e. Applications folder should be located inside a dot folder.

Comment: I guess your `find .` finds `.` and `Applications`, where other implementation(s) would find `.` and `./Applications`.

Comment: I have checked it earlier, my find outputs: dot folder on the first line and  ./Applications and the rest of the folders afterwards.

Comment: Please confirm you tested `find .` (not `find ./`) and got `./Applications`.

Comment: You cannot have a folder or directory named `.` that doesn't refer to your current working directory. I don't understand the concern about `./dir` vs `dir`. They are the same in either Linux or Mac OS environments. The Mac OS file system is not that wildly different from Linux file systems.

Comment: I've added screenshot of my find command and it's output. About dot directory I understand that in the Linux OS there is no differences when unpacking but the problem happens before unpacking the Mac installer shows error -1 when trying to install the pkg file containing my payload. I've not familiar with MAc or Mac development so my only option is to compare my install package with the working one and target the differences.